# Elastic Beanstalk Add more than one ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Docker, Django api application that can be called from multiple domains abc.xyx.com or def.lmn.com. I have added successfully the ssl certificate for abc.xyz.com from the configuration console in elastic beanstalk. That allows only one certificate to be added for 443 port.

How do i add the def.lmn.com certificate after creating it from aws certificate manager?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple SSL secured applications can be hosted in aws with each having their own SSL certificates with the help of SNI (Server Name Indication).
In order to achieve this you need to use an Application Load Balancer for your application. 
Hence, for  using SNI you need to bind multiple certificates to the same listener on your Application Load Balancer.

If you have not configured Application Load Balancer while creating your environment, then you need to create a new environment and configure it.
Configuring Application Load Balancer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html

Steps to be followed for adding multiple certificates, if you have configured Application Load Balancer while creating your Elastic Beanstalk Environment :

Step 1: Import/Upload all the certificates you require through “AWS Certificate Manager” service.

Step 2: Open your Load Balancer in the console.

Step 3: Go to the listeners tab, and select “view/edit certificates” .

Step 4: Now, use the “+” button in the top left corner and select the certificates you require. Then click the “Add” button.

That's it. In this way you can add multiple certificates to your application.

This can also done with the help of CLI using the following command:
aws elbv2 add-listener-certificates --listener-arn [listener-arn] --certificates CertificateArn=[cert-arn]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks will try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an application load balancer instead of an elastic  for your application. If you have an environment that already exists and you are not using an application load balancer then you need to create a new environment and while configuring the new environment specify the capacity as load balanced and select an application load balancer in the load balancer configuration. Once this is done then add a new listener for https. For now, select one certificate and launch your environment. Once your environment is launched, open the EC2 console and go to the loadbalancer in the sidebar. From there select your application loadbalancer, select your listener and click on view certificates. You can add multiple certificates, there.

Comment: Thanks will try that