# Configuring HTTPS for Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I deployed one web application to EB. I used Route 53 to redirect two domains to my application. On EB environment, it seems it only allows me to add one certificate to port 443 for my load balancer. Let's say my users only use my domain names to access my web application. How should I go about creating and adding SSL certificate(s) to secure the connections from those two domains to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add. In the EB concole, you can add only 1 SSL cert. To add other ones, you have to do it directly in the **EC2 console** on your load balancer.

The load balancer used by your EB env supports **multiple certificates**. So you can add extra SSL certificates to your HTTPS listener.

Helpful information is below:

- [How do I add multiple SSL certificates to the Application Load Balancer in my Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-ssl-load-balancer/)
- [How can I add certificates for multiple domains to an ELB using AWS Certificate Manager?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-add-domain-certificates-elb/)
- [Application Load Balancers Now Support Multiple TLS Certificates With Smart Selection Using SNI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/)
- [Elastic Beanstalk Add more than one ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299897/elastic-beanstalk-add-more-than-one-ssl-certificate)

Alternatively, you can register multiple domains under one certificate.

In the EC2 console, you have an option (marked below) to modify the SSL certificates for your HTTPS listener:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!

Comment: @Radar No problem. If my answer was helpful, it acceptance would be appreciated. Thanks.